# Aligning table to bottom of page

Tags: tables

I have a page that is filled with lots of text and at the bottom of the page there is a table

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\noindent\blindtext\par
\blindtext\par
\blindtext\par
\blindtext\par
\par\mbox{}\par
\vfill
\noindent\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}\hline
    A & B & C \\\hline
    D & E & F \\\hline
    G & H & I \\\hline
    J & K & L \\\hline
    M & N & O \\\hline
    Q & R & S \\\hline
    T & U & V \\\hline
    W & X & Y \\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

This is the result:
[image]

As you can see, the content of the last row (W, X and Y) aligns with the page frame. Is there a way to align the bottom line of the table with the page frame, i. e. lift the table up just a little bit?

Comment: Why you not use for your table a `{table}[b]` environment?

Comment: This seems to do the trick. Forgot about table environment. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrapping the table with a table environment as suggested by user Zarko in a comment to my question solved it for me.

```
\begin{table}[b]
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}\hline
    A & B & C \\\hline
    D & E & F \\\hline
    G & H & I \\\hline
    J & K & L \\\hline
    M & N & O \\\hline
    Q & R & S \\\hline
    T & U & V \\\hline
    W & X & Y \\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```