# Aligning table to bottom of page in a multi-column environment

Tags: tables, multicol

This is a follow-up question to [Aligning table to bottom of page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/638016/aligning-table-to-bottom-of-page). I have a two-column document consisting of text and tables. Sometimes the tables appear at the bottom of a column.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{multicol}
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols*}{2}
\noindent\blindtext\par
\blindtext
\par\mbox{}\par
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}\hline
    A & B & C \\\hline
    D & E & F \\\hline
    G & H & I \\\hline
    J & K & L \\\hline
    M & N & O \\\hline
    Q & R & S \\\hline
    T & U & V \\\hline
    W & X & Y \\\hline
    Z &   &   \\\hline
    A & B & C \\\hline
\end{tabular}
\columnbreak
\par
\blindtext\par
\blindtext\par
\end{multicols*}
\end{document}
```

This is the result:[image]

As you can see, the content of the last row of the table (A, B and C) aligns with the page frame. Is there a way to align the bottom line of the table with the page frame, i.e. lift the table up just a little bit? As far as I know, I cannot use the table environment inside a multi-column environment ; if I could, the problem would be solved.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I think `\begin{tabular}[b]{|c|c|c|}...\end{tabular}` should do, but I'm not familiar enough with `multicol`.

Comment: Yeah, that does work. Thanks a lot. Want to post an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by user campa in a comment to my question, adding `[b]` does the trick. I didn't realize you could add that to tabular as well. I though it's only available if you wrap tabular inside a table environment.